# meaning of "the binding is fragile"

Tags: idioms

what is the meaning of "The binding is fragile" ?
I saw it in one of the harry potters movie. But didn't know what it means
UPDATE: pretend that someone wants to take your book away from you and you don't want it to do.It insists and tells you why
you say "The binding is fragile"

Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely need more context.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm gussing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INFhqKaJdCw (that happens to be the #2 Google search result for "the binding is fragile")

Comment: Which word are you having difficulty with? "Binding" or "fragile"?

Comment: all of it, what it means at all?

Comment: It means that if the person doesn't handle the book with care it will come apart.  I.e., one should not open the book too widely or try to press it flat, or pick it up by the pages or by just one cover plus some pages and if you are opening it and start to hear sounds of the glue breaking you should stop immediately. Also if it's in a bookshelf, don't pull it out by hooking your finger into the top of the spine-  Be gentle with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Book binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookbinding) often involves the use of glues. Many of the older glue formulations become brittle over time.

Comment: And what it means? "The binding is fragile" was about a book that's right. But I don't know what it means

Comment: *Binding* here means the hard case into which the pages of the book are sewn and glued. *The binding is fragile* means *The binding is likely to break or disintegrate* if you abuse it.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for.